# Jquery datetimepicker startDate not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquerydatetimepicker

I am using jquery datetimepicker plugin for my project. I have created JavaScript function for create datepicker daynamically. Its working fine for all input text box. But i want to set startdate dynamically on show function. I have write code for it in setfromDate_limit function. In this function i have passed date control object. Its set min and max date perfectly but not start date. So please help me how to set startdate dynamically

Datetimepicker URL :http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

```
function create_datepicker(controlId,idx,flg_day,startday)
{
        var control="#"+controlId;
        var startdayflag=0;

        var cnt=jQuery(control).datetimepicker({
            format:'Y-m-d',
            scrollMonth:false,
            scrollInput:false,
            defineCustomWeekend:true,
            defaultSelect:defaultselect.replace(/\-/g, '/'),
            startDate:"<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>",
            onClose:function(){
                if(flg_day)
                {
                    calulate_days(idx);
                }
            },
            onChangeDateTime:function(){
                if(flg_day)
                {
                    for (i = idx+1; i < $( "input[name ^=end_dt]").length; i++) { 
                        $("#start_dt_"+i).val("");
                        $("#end_dt_"+i).val("");
                        $("#no_of_days_"+i).val("");
                    }
                }
            },
            onShow:function(){
                if(flg_day)
                {   
                    setDate_limit(this,idx) // to date
                }
                else{
                    setfromDate_limit(this,idx) // from date
                }
            },
            timepicker:false
    });
}


function setfromDate_limit(obj,idx)
    {
        if(idx == 0)
            return;
        else if(idx == 0 && obj=='')
            return;
        else
            var full_date=get_prev_date(idx);
            if(full_date != '')
            {
                var actualDate = new Date(full_date);
                //alert(actualDate);
                actualDate.setDate(actualDate.getDate()+1);
                full_date=actualDate.getFullYear()+"/"+(actualDate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+actualDate.getDate();
                var startday=actualDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(actualDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+actualDate.getDate();
                var mindt=full_date;
                //obj.startDate="2015-09-19";
                obj.setOptions({
                    startDate:startday,
                    minDate:mindt,
                    maxDate:mindt
                    })

                return;
            }
            return;
    }
```

Comment: why you put `<?php ... ?>` in double quotes

Comment: @AmitSoni I have write this code in my php script and i want to set server date instead of client PC date so i wrote this

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sy7hfxa7/1/

use `formatDate:'Y-m-d'` to set pattern for `startDate`

Comment: are you right but i want to set stardDate dynamically same as minimum date and maximum date. See my function setfromDate_limit in my question